# Table Cell Dynamic Change

Tags: html, border, cell

I'm working on a project which requires display of a set of product images and links in a tables and would like to implement the dynamic changing of a table cell on mouse over like they do on The Find http://www.thefind.com.

When you do a search and mouse over any table cell on the results page, the cell border changes to a raised 3-D type of border.

I'm wondering how to implement that effect?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery would be my way to go on this.

You could give a class to your table td's like `<td class="niceBorder"></td>`

Then either in an external .js file or in script tags in the head section of the page you can simply do somethign like the following:

```
$(".niceBorder").hover(function(){
     $(this).css("border", "2px outset silver");
})
```

Make sure to include the jQuery library in your page before the .js file or the script tags in the head section.

Comment: Have a look at this for a bigger example http://www.devcurry.com/2009/02/change-table-border-color-on-hover_27.html

Comment: Thank you so much. I reviewed your code and studied the page you linked to and it's working great!

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few different ways to go about it, give a few of these tuts a look:

http://css-tricks.com/row-and-column-highlighting/

Pure CSS:  http://www.designisphilosophy.com/microsoft-expression-web/fancy-interactive-pure-css-list-boxes-with-hover-effect/